# FullCalendar in Android Simulator

Tags: jquery-mobile, android-emulator, fullcalendar

My goal is to include a FullCalendar into JQueryMobile.
I have followed this guide but when I run it with the Android Emulator, it loads the event dialog page with input text "title" and "color" like the image below.
[click my image](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5dnb9JhVY-8cWhGQ1NlQzJTYzQ)

How can I make it load a full calendar view first instead of an event dialog?
[click my image](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5dnb9JhVY-8ZW5GS1dQeFdQcDQ)

I have copied all js & css. Here is my index.html code

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='resources/css/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css'/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='resources/css/fullcalendar.css'/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='resources/css/application.css'/>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='resources/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='resources/js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='resources/js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='resources/js/underscore.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='resources/js/backbone.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='resources/js/application.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>       

    <div id='eventDialog' class='dialog ui-helper-hidden'>
        <form>
            <div>
                <label>Title:</label>
                <input id='title' class="field" type="text"></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Color:</label>
                <input id='color' class="field" type="text"></input>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

Please advise how to load full calendar view instead of the event dialog coming first.

Comment: Add ons - I have followed this guide
http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/05/building-a-shared-calendar-with-backbone-js-and-fullcalendar-a-step-by-step-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/defaultView/

It's covered in the documentation. Is your defaultView set to 'month'?